# Prevent the "Are you sure you want to reload this page?" popup from appearing when I refresh/close/leave the page after I view the edits

Tags: support, popup

I have been encountering this issue for the second time today.

Suppose I press <kbd>edit</kbd> button to edit a question. Another user that has more than 2K reputation edited the post during this time. I see the "an edit has made ot this post; click to reload" message and click it. The question refreshes with the edit. I press any other link or close the tab or refresh the page and then the following popup message appears:

> #### Confirm Navigation/reload
>
> You have started writing or editing a post.
>
> Are you sure you want to reload/leave the page?
>
> <kbd>Reload this page</kbd>   <kbd>don't reload this page</kbd>

This popup shouldn't appear as I've already pressed the "an edit has made ot this post; click to reload" message and whatever I've edited is lost.

Comment: Just got annoyed enough by this to see if someone else has already reported it.  IMO this should be retagged as bug, not support.